PHP-CS-FIXER: Remove extra indentation on multi-line shorthand if else (ternary operator)
Is it possible to remove extra indentation on multiple line shorthand if/else statement in PHP-CS-FIXER?
The code below is just an example but in real scenario, results of true and false may be longer and multi-line is a better approach.
Current class:
<?php

class Test
{
    public function __invoke($var = 100): bool
    {
        return $var = 100
                        ? true
                        : false;
    }
}

Desired result
<?php

class Test
{
    public function __invoke($var = 100): bool
    {
        return $var = 100
            ? true
            : false;
    }
}

PHP-CS-FIXER rules
$rules = [
    /** PHP arrays should be declared using the configured syntax. */
    'array_syntax' => ['syntax' => 'short'],

    /** Binary operators should be surrounded by space as configured. */
    'binary_operator_spaces' => [
        'default' => 'single_space',
        'operators' => ['=>' => null]
    ],

    /** There MUST be one blank line after the namespace declaration. */
    'blank_line_after_namespace' => true,

    /** Ensure there is no code on the same line as the PHP open tag and it is followed by a blank line. */
    'blank_line_after_opening_tag' => true,

    /** An empty line feed must precede any configured statement. */
    'blank_line_before_statement' => [
        'statements' => ['return']
    ],

    /** The body of each structure MUST be enclosed by braces. Braces should be properly placed. Body of braces should be properly indented. */
    'braces' => true,

    /** A single space or none should be between cast and variable. */
    'cast_spaces' => true,

    /** Class, trait and interface elements must be separated with one or none blank line. */
    'class_attributes_separation' => [
        'elements' => ['method' => 'one'],
    ],

    /** Whitespace around the keywords of a class, trait or interfaces definition should be one space. */
    'class_definition' => true,

    /** Concatenation should be spaced according configuration. */
    'concat_space' => [
        'spacing' => 'one'
    ],

    /** Equal sign in declare statement should be surrounded by spaces or not following configuration. */
    'declare_equal_normalize' => true,

    /** The keyword elseif should be used instead of else if so that all control keywords look like single words. */
    'elseif' => true,

    /** PHP code MUST use only UTF-8 without BOM (remove BOM). */
    'encoding' => true,

    /** PHP code must use the long <?php tags or short-echo <?= tags and not other tag variations. */
    'full_opening_tag' => true,

    /** Transforms imported FQCN parameters and return types in function arguments to short version. */
    'fully_qualified_strict_types' => true,

    /** Spaces should be properly placed in a function declaration. */
    'function_declaration' => true,

    /** nsure single space between function's argument and its typehint. */
    'function_typehint_space' => true,

    /** Convert heredoc to nowdoc where possible. */
    'heredoc_to_nowdoc' => true,

    /** Include/Require and file path should be divided with a single space. File path should not be placed under brackets. */
    'include' => true,

    /** Pre- or post-increment and decrement operators should be used if possible. */
    'increment_style' => ['style' => 'post'],

    /** Code MUST use configured indentation type. */
    'indentation_type' => true,

    /** Ensure there is no code on the same line as the PHP open tag. */
    'linebreak_after_opening_tag' => true,

    /** All PHP files must use same line ending. */
    'line_ending' => true,

    /** Cast should be written in lower case. */
    'lowercase_cast' => true,

    /** The PHP constants true, false, and null MUST be written using the correct casing. */
    'constant_case' => true,

    /** PHP keywords MUST be in lower case. */
    'lowercase_keywords' => true,

    /** Class static references self, static and parent MUST be in lower case. */
    'lowercase_static_reference' => true,

    /** Magic method definitions and calls must be using the correct casing. */
    'magic_method_casing' => true,

    /** Magic constants should be referred to using the correct casing */
    'magic_constant_casing' => true,

    /**
     * In method arguments and method call, there MUST NOT be a space before each comma and
     * there MUST be one space after each comma. Argument lists MAY be split across multiple
     * lines, where each subsequent line is indented once. When doing so, the first item in the
     * list MUST be on the next line, and there MUST be only one argument per line.
     */
    // 'method_argument_space' => true,
    'method_argument_space' => [
        'on_multiline' => 'ignore', // This will prevent extra indentation on multiline method arguments
        'keep_multiple_spaces_after_comma' => false,
    ],

    /** Function defined by PHP should be called using the correct casing. */
    'native_function_casing' => true,

    /** (risky) Master functions shall be used instead of aliases. */
    'no_alias_functions' => true,

    /** Removes extra blank lines and/or blank lines following configuration. */
    'no_extra_blank_lines' => [
        'tokens' => [
            'extra',
            'throw',
            'use',
            'use_trait',
        ]
    ],
    /** There should be no empty lines after class opening brace. */
    'no_blank_lines_after_class_opening' => true,
    'no_blank_lines_after_phpdoc' => true,
    'no_closing_tag' => true,
    'no_empty_phpdoc' => true,
    'no_empty_statement' => true,
    'no_leading_import_slash' => true,
    'no_leading_namespace_whitespace' => true,
    'no_mixed_echo_print' => [
        'use' => 'echo'
    ],
    'no_multiline_whitespace_around_double_arrow' => true,
    'multiline_whitespace_before_semicolons' => [
        'strategy' => 'no_multi_line'
    ],
    'no_short_bool_cast' => true,
    'no_singleline_whitespace_before_semicolons' => true,
    'no_spaces_after_function_name' => true,
    'no_spaces_around_offset' => true,
    'no_spaces_inside_parenthesis' => true,
    'no_trailing_comma_in_list_call' => true,
    'no_trailing_comma_in_singleline_array' => true,
    'no_trailing_whitespace' => true,
    'no_trailing_whitespace_in_comment' => true,
    'no_unneeded_control_parentheses' => true,
    'no_unused_imports' => true,

    /* (risky) In function arguments there must not be arguments with default values before non-default ones. */
    'no_unreachable_default_argument_value' => true,

    'no_useless_return' => true,
    'no_whitespace_before_comma_in_array' => true,
    'no_whitespace_in_blank_line' => true,
    'normalize_index_brace' => true,
    'not_operator_with_successor_space' => true,
    'object_operator_without_whitespace' => true,
    'ordered_imports' => ['sort_algorithm' => 'alpha'],
    'phpdoc_indent' => true,
    'general_phpdoc_tag_rename' => true,
    'phpdoc_inline_tag_normalizer' => true,
    'phpdoc_tag_type' => true,
    'phpdoc_no_access' => true,
    'phpdoc_no_package' => true,
    'phpdoc_no_useless_inheritdoc' => true,
    'phpdoc_scalar' => true,
    'phpdoc_single_line_var_spacing' => true,
    'phpdoc_summary' => true,
    'phpdoc_to_comment' => true,
    'phpdoc_trim' => true,
    'phpdoc_types' => true,
    'phpdoc_var_without_name' => true,

    /* (risky) Classes must be in a path that matches their namespace, be at least one namespace deep and the class name should match the file name. */
    'psr_autoloading' => true,

    /* (risky) Inside class or interface element self should be preferred to the class name itself. */
    'self_accessor' => true,

    'short_scalar_cast' => true,
    'simplified_null_return' => false, // disabled by Shift
    'single_blank_line_at_eof' => true,
    'single_blank_line_before_namespace' => true,
    'single_class_element_per_statement' => true,
    'single_import_per_statement' => true,
    'single_line_after_imports' => true,
    'single_line_comment_style' => [
        'comment_types' => ['hash']
    ],
    'single_quote' => true,
    'space_after_semicolon' => true,
    'standardize_not_equals' => true,
    'switch_case_semicolon_to_colon' => true,
    'switch_case_space' => true,
    'ternary_operator_spaces' => true,
    'trailing_comma_in_multiline' => ['elements' => ['arrays']],
    'trim_array_spaces' => true,
    'unary_operator_spaces' => true,
    'visibility_required' => [
        'elements' => ['method', 'property']
    ],
    'whitespace_after_comma_in_array' => true,
    'escape_implicit_backslashes' => false,
    'type_declaration_spaces' => true,
    'method_chaining_indentation' => true,
    'array_indentation' => true,
    'return_type_declaration' => true,
];

The rules is pretty long.
The closest keyword I could guess for my issue is the ternary_operator_spaces rule but this only applies to fixing single space in between the condition in a single line.
